# sudo update-alternatives --config . How to set the auto entry

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

I'm trying to run a script that does somewhere: `python setup.py egg_info`
This gives me an error.
But if I manually do : `python3 setup.py egg_info` I don't get the error.

Therefore I tried to `sudo update-alternatives --config python` . This gives:

```
  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.10   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3      1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.10   2         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.8    0         manual mode
```

This should redirect the script to the right version of python.
But it still doesn't work . My guess is that it is because python3.10 is still the auto mode version.

Is there something I can do about this?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `python` and `python3` symlinks in `/etc/alternatives/` (e.g. with `ls -lF /etc/alternatives/python*`.

My guess is that `python` points to `python3.8` while `python3` points to `python3.10`.  Or vice-versa.

Is there any particular reason why you want `python` to run 3.8 instead of 3.10?  if not, run update-alternatives again and set it to either auto (preferred) or to 3.10 (you'll run into the same problem in future when 3.11 or 3.12 or whatever is the latest auto version).

Or just make sure that the alternatives symlinks for `python` **and** `python3` point to the same version of python.

Comment: … or avoid using alternatives for Python altogether since that’s not how it’s supposed to be set up in Debian or Ubuntu (and yes, I am aware that it is given as a solution all over the Internet). Ubuntu has a `python-is-python3` package for this.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah, I though that was odd but just assumed that's how Ubuntu does it.  I noticed when I checked on my Debian machines, that there are no python symlinks (for any version) in `/etc/alternatives` (and I don't currently have an ubuntu machine or VM to check with).

Comment: @cas Thanks, I'll try that. Reason why I temporarily want to try this is because of the above error trying to compile sagemath prerequisite package pygments-2.10.0 It gave me the above error whilst I noticed that python3 instead of python didn't.